# How to connect to a MySQL Database with JDBC using Electron

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, electron

So I've been tinkering (fresh out of college) with creating a DB app via Electron as practice. I've successfully created a Java-only program that uses JDBC to connect to an MySQL database, but now I have to integrate that with an Electron GUI somehow and frankly I have no idea how to proceed.

Most things I've searched explain that connecting to a database via JavaScript is possible though completely not recommended due to the security issues, so I'd like to do this as securely as possible.

Would anyone know how to run Java within an Electron application to connect to a database, or is there some other method I'm overlooking that makes this seemingly Sisyphean task more simple?

Sorry for the possible ignorance here, still learning the ins and outs of different frameworks and such. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like [dba.se] might be the better site for you sir. That site is all about databases where we here are more concerned about programming.

Comment: @TheGrandJ thanks for the recommendation, I'll post over there!

Comment: Javascript is no less secure in connecting to a mysal database than any other programming language.

Answer (score 0):

You should use node.js to access mysql. I find some example as below to be helpful to you.
Pls see here https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/259/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-in-electron-framework

To avoid link page unavailable, I pasted code here:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

// Add the credentials to access your database
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : null, // or the original password : 'apaswword'
    database : 'ourcodeworld-database'
});

// connect to mysql
connection.connect(function(err) {
    // in case of error
    if(err){
        console.log(err.code);
        console.log(err.fatal);
    }
});

// Perform a query
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `myTableName` LIMIT 10';

connection.query($query, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if(err){
        console.log("An error ocurred performing the query.");
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }

    console.log("Query succesfully executed", rows);
});

// Close the connection
connection.end(function(){
    // The connection has been closed
});
```

If you want your application more secure, you can follow these solution.

** solution 1: package your electron into exe file. so db connection info can not be seen by others. You can find more suggestion in this site.

** solution 2: You can build an independent service to process mysql DB using node.js or Java(Spring). Then using restful in https to access service to obtain info from DB. It is secure too

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your response. I thought using node.js to connect to a MySQL DB was unsafe? Is the information sent/requested encrypted?

Comment: Please read [answer]. Do not just post links and say "go here" You need to explain why that link is important/helpful and provide a quote of the most relevant information.

Comment: Electron can be packaged to exe file. so db connection info can not seen by others. The other solution is that you can build a depend service to process mysql using node.js. then using restful in https to access service to obtain info from mysql. It is secure too.

Comment: I have retracted my flag now. This is now an answer. I would suggest you expand on it and explain more how rather than what to do. And like we said please excerpt data from the link that is specifically helpful (in case the link ever stops working). Other than that I'm going to vote up your answer now.

Comment: Looking better and better! This looks very close to the sort of answers we expect. I'd say you'd just need to explain what that code actually does so others will know why it answers the question. Other than that good job and if others look here you might get more upvotes